# Finding Max date in hive

Tags: hive

I have a column named "Date" which is in string datatype. 
01-24-2018
04-30-2017

How to find the maximum of these dates which is in string?

I used this query which is not returning the expected max.

```
max(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(b.Date,'MM-dd-yyyy')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
MAX( cast(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(yourdate , 'MM-dd-yyyy'))) as date))
```

**EDIT**: In your comments you mentioned you need to get the account details for the max date.You could use this.

```
SELECT a.id,
       b.contract,
       CAST (
          TO_DATE (
             from_unixtime (unix_timestam‌​p (b.date, 'MM-dd-yyyy'))) AS DATE)
          AS MAX_DATE
  FROM acct a JOIN customer b ON (b.partyid = a.offerid)
 WHERE CAST (
          TO_DATE (
             from_unixtime (unix_timestam‌​p (b.date, 'MM-dd-yyyy'))) AS DATE) IN 

  ( SELECT 
         MAX (
            CAST (
               TO_DATE (
                  from_unixtime (unix_timestam‌​p (b.date, 'MM-dd-yyyy'))) AS DATE))
    FROM acct a JOIN customer b ON (b.partyid = a.offerid)
   WHERE b.contract = 200427747 );
```

Comment: Still I am getting the two dates .. not the max .... This is the query I am using Select a.id,b.contract,MAX(cast(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(b.date , 'MM-dd-yyyy'))) as date)) 
from acct a JOIN customer b on (b.partyid=a.offerid) 
where b.contract=200427747 
GROUP BY b.contract,b.date,a.id;

Comment: Should I pass that in where clause?

Comment: Remove group by and other columns in select

Comment: Yeah its working fine... But I wanted to have Group By for other attributes as well.... How to find max of dates for this alone ....

Comment: @SRIRAMRAMACHANDRAN  You did not clearly mention this in your question. Not clear why you were using group by if that was the expected output. If you use group by , it is going to retrieve multiple rows. I have modified my answer accordingly. Let me know if it works.